# How to convert a list of integer lists to an integer list Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integer lists. I am trying to convert it to a list of integers.

```
int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

new_list = []
for i in int_list:
    new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Wanted output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

My output:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: `new_list.append(i[0])`

Comment: Alternatively, `new_list.extend(i)`

Answer (score 2):

A very pythonic way of doing this would be to use list comprehension:

```
int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]    

new_list = [value for sub_list in int_list for value in sub_list]
print(new_list)
```

An explaination of this can be found here: https://spapas.github.io/2016/04/27/python-nested-list-comprehensions/

There are many more ways that some people would prefer, for example a programmer who uses functional programming may prefer:

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]    
print(reduce(add, int_list))
```

If you want a more verbose and easier to understand version, you could use:

```
int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

new_list = []
for i in int_list:
    new_list.extend(i)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it:

```
int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]    

new_list = []
for i in int_list:
    new_list.append(i[0])

print(new_list)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
int_list = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

new_list = []
for i in int_list:
    new_list += i  

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use itemgetter with map

```
from operator import itemgetter


new_list = list(map(itemgetter(0), int_list))

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

2) or you can use [chain](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from itertools

```
from itertools import chain

new_list = list(chain(*int_list))

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```